# Android Studio JNI: Loop of ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm creating a C++ Android APP based of the book Pro Android NDK and this tutorial (http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Android.html#Android_example_class)

I created a C++ class called Http that creates sockets to perform simple HTTP requests (mostly for learning purposes). The C++ app works on its own. 
I compiled it to JNI (using Swig) and generated the appropriate JNI code and the Java "proxy" files which I can use to call the code.

My original C++ constructor has this signature:
`Http::Http(const char * ip_address, int port)`

1) In my AndroidStudio app I have an Activity called **MainActivity**.  The Package containing the MainActivity and the generated JNI Java classes is **com.zuzile**. My default constructor looks like this `SWIGEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_zuzile_exampleJNI_new_1Http(JNIEnv *jenv, jclass jcls, jstring jarg1, jint jarg2)` where "exampleJNI" is my Java class that contains the native method `public final static native long new_Http(String jarg1, int jarg2);`

2) After generating the appropriate JNI and corresponding Java classes I successfully compiled the JNI code into a .so file using NDK. I was able to load the .so file by calling `System.loadLibrary("httpreq")` httpreq is the name of my compiled module.

3) When I try to use my Module by calling Http("some IP address", "a port") I get the following error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.zuzile.MainActivity` (as output by the Debugger).

If I remove the `Http(...)` declaration from my MainActivity.java my APP loads perfectly without crashing. But as soon as I use the Native code I generated it states it can't find com.zuzile.MainActivity.

I appreciate any help in advance as I've been stuck on this for 3 days now.

Answer (score 0):

JNI is just an interface between JAVA and C/C++, you can't map directly c++ class to Jave class. you can just call mapped methods.

In your case, Http("some IP address", "a port") means java constructor, but you don't have a java class named "Http", right?

Comment: hmm I do have a an Http Java class. The Http Java class is used as  "proxy" or bridge. My Http Java class calls my actual JNI class file.

My structure is as follows:
1) JNI code compiled to .so
2) HttpJNI Java library that has the proper signatures/names to call the .so library form step 1
3) An intermediate Http Java class that resembles my original C++ class, but internally it calls the httpJNI java class from step 2.